# Cannot insert row in Postgres using Ansible and Jinja

Tags: python, postgresql, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have an Ansible playbook to backup sono devices, everything seems to work except when I try to insert the backup (and the differences, if any, with another backup) into a Postgres Database for two specific hosts out of 700+.

I think that the problem is with some special characters that need to be replace or escaped, I'm already escaping single quotes in my task but I guess there are other problematic characters.

Is there a way to escape/replace all the characaters in a task via Jinja (or something else)?

Those are the task that are currently run to insert backups without and with differences.

```yaml
---
- name: Insert row with backup without difference
  vars:
    backup_column: "{{ backup_column }}"
  local_action:        
    module: community.postgresql.postgresql_query        
    login_host: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_host") }}'
    login_password: '{{ networking_db_password }}'
    login_user: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_user") }}'
    db: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_db") }}'
    port: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_port")|int }}'
    query: INSERT INTO backup
            (inventory_id, {{ backup_column }}, backup_done, backup_date, backup_ping, backup_ssh_connection,
            backup_ssh_authentication)
            VALUES
            ('{{ networking_id }}',
              '{{ new_config|regex_replace("[']", "''")}}', True, NOW(), '{{ ping }}', True, True)
```

```yaml
---
- name: Insert row with backup and differences
  vars:
    backup_column: "{{ backup_column }}"
  local_action:        
    module: community.postgresql.postgresql_query        
    login_host: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_host") }}'
    login_password: '{{ networking_db_password }}'
    login_user: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_user") }}'
    db: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_db") }}'
    port: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_port")|int }}'
    query: INSERT INTO backup
            (inventory_id, {{ backup_column }}, last_backup_diff, backup_done, backup_date, backup_ping, backup_ssh_connection,
            backup_ssh_authentication)
            VALUES
            ('{{ networking_id }}',
              '{{ new_config|regex_replace("[']", "''") }}', 
      '{{ backup_diff.diff_text|regex_replace("[']", "''") }}', True, NOW(), '{{ ping }}', True, True)
```

The error is pretty generic

```
msg": "Cannot execute SQL 'INSERT INTO backup (inventory_id, backup_rsc, backup_done, backup_date, backup_ping, backup_ssh_connection, backup_ssh_authentication) VALUES ('4210',...
```

I can't paste what's in the backup since those are company information but the error seems to be:

```
None: syntax error at or near \"4\"\nLINE 129: ...r $1a$}~-(&1J|xE$0XvxCrfK7BLr&7V0p8g;x&EkV@+:o85z&4''ce\\''4$\n ^\n
```

So I think is a problem with single/double quotes or some other "special" character, but when I try to insert that string directly instead of reading from the {{ new_config }} everything seems to work.

Comment: `I can't paste what's in the backup since those are company information.` <= you are responsible for making a [mre]. If you can't paste the information, reproduce the problem with information you can paste. As far as I can see with the partial info, you simply have a syntax error in your sql query. Spotting it without the complete error message is just impossible.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the edit first of all, I probably pasted the wrong task while I was trying to debug that was the problem, I'll come back with an example of the error as soon as possible!

Comment: Could you please search for the entire error message? For example in the PostgreSQL logfiles.

Comment: @FrankHeikens what i get from Ansible is None: syntax error at or near \"4\"\nLINE 129: ...r $1a$}~-(&1J|xE$0XvxCrfK7BLr&7V0p8g;x&EkV@+:o85z&4''ce\\''4$\n ^\n 

So I guess it is a problem with single/double quotes but when i try to insert that string after setting an Ansible fact it does work..

Comment: How do you avoid SQL injection in Ansible?

Comment: @FrankHeikens although this might not cover all injections aspects: 1) you can check for possible dangerous values in connection role setting the parameter [`trust_input: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_query_module.html#parameter-trust_input) 2) You can escape the variables in [query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_query_module.html#parameter-trust_input) using psycopg2 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the module documentazion again and testing some possible solution, I ended up solving the issue using positional_args and %s in the task, like:

```
---
- name: Insert row with backup and differences
  vars:
    backup_column: "{{ backup_column }}"
  local_action:
    module: community.postgresql.postgresql_query
    login_host: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_host") }}'
    login_password: '{{ networking_db_password }}'
    login_user: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_user") }}'
    db: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_db") }}'
    port: '{{ lookup("ansible.builtin.env","networking_pg_port")|int }}'
    query: INSERT INTO backup
            (inventory_id, {{ backup_column }}, last_backup_diff, backup_done, backup_date, backup_ping, backup_ssh_connection,
            backup_ssh_authentication)
            VALUES
            (%s,%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    positional_args:
      - "{{ networking_id }}"
      - "{{ new_config }}"
      - "{{ backup_diff.diff_text }}"
      - True
      - NOW()
      - "{{ ping }}"
      - True
      - True
```

I also kept the task without the %s and added a check to execute the insert with positional args only when the "original" insert fails.

Comment: `I also kept the task without the %s and added a check to execute the insert with positional args only when the "original" insert fails.` so you basically kept your original task wide open to sql injections to use a much safer one only when it falls... Why would you do that now you have one fixing the issue in all situations? What if your original task doesn't fail but ruins your db because of malicious data in your vars?